# neo4j allow_store_upgrade causing application not to start

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I am trying to setup a spring project with neo4j. However, when I run the application it does not start up and give the following exception:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'videoRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in class path resource [spring/neo4j.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@147e32a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

  org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnableToUpgradeException: Not all store files match the version required for successful upgrade
```

Here is my neo4j.xml

```
<neo4j:repositories base-package="neo4j.repository"/> 
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>  
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg value="C:/Users/mario/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I am assuming that this problem is caused by allow_store_upgrade. If I remove or set this property to false a exception is thrown suggesting to me to set it to true. What is really causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please share your database logs: `C:/Users/mario/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/messages.log`

Comment: Make sure that no server is running at the same time, using the same DB-directory.

Comment: The exception that is thrown suggesting to fix it means that you have an older/incompatible store version? Is that a directory of a 2.0 server? If so you cannot run your 1.9 SDN 2.3.1 app against the same data. You have to wait for SDN 3.0.M1 or use an older 1.9.4 server.

Comment: Thanks alot guys. I Downgraded the SDN and it works now

Comment: I am having similar problem, can you please update what SDN version did worked?